# Mysql select query count & Distinct are not working properly

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, sum, left-join

I am developing an eCommerce website using Laravel 8. I write the following script for find out total price & total quantity under a single order number. From following script getting the ERROR where is the problem please help me.
*At first I write row mysql then i will convert laravel query Builder.

```
SELECT COUNT (total_price) as totaPrice, COUNT (productqty) as proQnty
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT order_id FROM orderDetails)
LEFT JOIN ordertbl 
ON ordertbl.id = orderDetails.order_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to sum the prices and quantities, so use `SUM()` aggregate function.
Also you should do a `LEFT` join of `ordertbl` to `orderDetails` and not the other way around:

```
SELECT ot.id,
       SUM(od.total_price) AS totaPrice, 
       SUM(od.productqty) AS proQnty
FROM ordertbl ot LEFT JOIN orderDetails od
ON ot.id = od.order_id
WHERE ot.id = ?
GROUP BY ot.id;
```

Or, without a join:

```
SELECT SUM(total_price) AS totaPrice, 
       SUM(productqty) AS proQnty
FROM orderDetails 
WHERE order_id = ?;
```

Replace `?` with the `id` of the order that you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Your raw in missing the tablename alis for the subquery ..
Your raw query should be

```
SELECT COUNT(total_price) as totaPrice, COUNT(productqty) as proQnty
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT order_id FROM orderDetails
) T 
LEFT JOIN ordertbl ON ordertbl.id = T.order_id;
```

Comment: Sorry run this script showing following error "Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100421. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error"

Comment: answer  updated ..  remove space between count and ( ..  let me know

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT order_id, COUNT(total_price) as totaPrice, COUNT(productqty) as proQnty FROM orderDetails LEFT JOIN ordertbl ON ordertbl.id = orderDetails.order_id;
this is the right script.  working properly. I  have another script I want to discuss with you.